# Is it possible for 2 users to log in to the same Windows machine at the same time with separate GUI sessions?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

I wonder if 2 users can use a single Windows machine with different GUI sessions remotely. For example, user A login to the machine and do his web browsing and at the same time user B login and do his tasks. If it is possible, how to set up the Windows machine this way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one user can use a Windows workstation locally. Two (or more) users can be logged in and you can switch users. That works fine. But only one user at a time.

Remote tools normally log the user out

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. This is only available in Windows Server

Comment: Or with a hack that we won't discuss here, but that's widely available on the Internet if you search for it...

Comment: Can you clarify? I am doing a pen-testing session and I really need this feature.

Comment: You can log in remotely as the same user using proper tools, but not two users.

Comment: @Didier Is the hack you are talking about is using the Windows Server dll?

Comment: Didier said they would not discuss here. @Benassin

Comment: Sorry, I will not discuss anymore.

Comment: "Google is your friend..."

Comment: [Thinstuff](https://www.thinstuff.com/products/xpvs-server/) allows that with Windows 10, however a Windows Server provides 2 connections already without additional RDS CALs